# PHP shell_exec using UNC paths

Tags: php, system, shell-exec

In PHP, I can not execute a command via shell_exec, system, or exec, when using unc paths.
Here is an example:

What works:

```
$command = shell_exec("dir c:\\"); echo $command;
```

Here is what does not work. It echo's nothing.

```
$command = shell_exec("dir \\\\server\\dir"); echo $command;
```

When I run **dir \\server\dir** in the Windows Command window or PowerShell it executes fine.

Comment: Is the user account running the web server (for example Apache) the same as the one you're logged into? Also, you might want to try `net use` to assign a drive letter to the remote directory.

Comment: Don't use backslashes in paths, even if you're coding for Windows. PHP will auto-translate to the appropriate delimiter, just stick with normal forward slashes. Try `dir //server/dir` instead.

Answer (score 1):

UNC paths will work, however the user that the PHP service is running as must have access to the share.

I will assume you are running PHP with IIS. If that is the case, the default user is [IUSR_MachineName](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis). Be sure this user has access to the share.

If you're running Apache, check the Task Manager on the server to determine which user is running the Apache service. Give this user name access to the share.

Comment: PHP is running on IIS, How can I change the user from IUSR_<MachoneName> to another account?

Comment: Perhaps this question on Server Fault will help you: http://serverfault.com/questions/83947/iis7-running-a-site-under-a-limited-user-account